Jenkins - let user define application version number before build
How to enable user to define which application version to build?
I have docker services and I update the version by manually editing docker-compose files with the new version and then building in Jenkins. I would love to simplify this by changing the version in a Jenkins job.
I was thinking of adding the version as a variable in docker-compose file  image: docker-new.test.net/bo:${version}
but now I'm stuck as to how to enable user to add value for this variable in a Jenkins job.
